# Get a reference to a local scope from a function

Tags: javascript, scope

Let's say I have this code:

```
// somewhere else
var outFn = (() => {
  var local = 5;
  var fn = () => { console.log(local); };
  return fn;
})();

// I have a reference to outFn
outFn(); // prints 5
```

How to get a reference to `outFn`'s local scope, that is, how to get a reference to `local` variable using my reference to `outFn`?

Comment: You can't......

Comment: Yah, the dev side(lib in your case)doesn't want to give the client side(your code) the access to the internal data structure is the reason an IIFE is used instead of a object literal, my guess;)

Comment: I agree :) I shouldn't. But is there a way to hack it? :P Just because I shouldn't doesn't mean I can't ;)

Comment: Well, I'm hoping I can, that is. That's the question: is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Don't write the last parentheses :

```
var outFn = (() => {
  var local = 5;
  var fn = () => { console.log(local); };
  return fn;
}) //(); <-- No need those parentheses
```

Then :

```
  var localFn= outFn(); 
  localFn() ; // prints 5
```

If you want to access also to `local` variable also , attach it to `fn` like following :

```
var outFn = (() => {
  var fn = () => { console.log(fn.local); };
  fn.local = 5;
  return fn;
});
```

Now you can read `local` :

```
  var localFn= outFn(); 
  localFn.local ; // ===5
```

Comment: But what if I can't change the "somewhere else" code? That is, well, somewhere else. I only have the reference outFn now...

Comment: @LuanNico Do you mean you hotlink it from an external server? Just upload the modified code to your site.

Comment: I mean I'm writing a lib that needs to do that for a given client code. Nothing like that rs Just don't have access to the declaration bit of the code, that's all.

Comment: The closure returned from outFn is the only tie outFn local scope connect to the outside, useful for access controls, why in your case want to break this kind of encapsulation?

Comment: Because let's say I want to make a profiler, I wanna make a function that receives and function and returns that function wrapper in some code. That works, but let's say the original function is recursive, how could I update the recursive calls? I was using eval and string manipulation (I know, evil, but that's the hack), but I need a reference to the original scope to re-eval the function...